# Classify Turing Machine as Decidable, Co-recognizable, Recognizable

Tags: automata, turing-machines, decidability

Consider the language
L = {: M is a TM and M visits its start state at least twice when executed on ε}.
Prove L with respect to decidability, recognizability, and co-recognizability.

I think the problem is recognizable, but not co-recognizable. I am trying to reduce the problem to halting problem in order to prove this. I am not sure how to create a Turing Machine for the reduction.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think the problem is recognizable, but not co-recognizable. I am trying to reduce the problem to halting problem in order to prove this. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: I suggest you add that information to the question body as it details what you have attempted and provides more context.

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Do you happen to know how to approach this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. I was just browsing MSE when I came across this question and thought some additional context is required. However there are other users on this site who do and you shouldn't worry about the current lack of attention.